# How to process a data from one component to another sibling component in React?

Tags: reactjs, state, jsx

Recap:

There are four components `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` and a data `originalData`

1. Pass `originalData` to A, and get processing result named `dataFromA`.
2. Pass `dataFromA` to B, and get processing result named `dataFromB`.
3. Pass `dataFromB` to C, and get processing result named `dataFromC`.
4. Pass `dataFromC` to D, and get processing result named `dataFromD`.
5. Return `dataFromD` to parent component.

The corresponding code in my mind is

```js
const TestComponent = ({originalData, getReturn}) => {
    const [dataFromA, setDataFromA] = useState();
    const [dataFromB, setDataFromB] = useState();
    const [dataFromC, setDataFromC] = useState();
    const [dataFromD, setDataFromD] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        getReturn.call(null, dataFromD);
    }, [getReturn, dataFromD])

    return (
        <>
            <A data={originalData} getReturn={(data) => setDataFromA(data)}/>
            <B data={dataFromA} getReturn={(data) => setDataFromB(data)}/>
            <C data={dataFromB} getReturn={(data) => setDataFromC(data)}/>
            <D data={dataFromC} getReturn={(data) => setDataFromD(data)}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Does it have a more concise implementation?

This is a problem in my real project, just a simpler description for everyone to understand. [Source code](https://github.com/weirenxue/ap-displayer/blob/v2.0-alpha.0/src/components/APFilter.js) may help you understand my pain points.

Comment: implement redux and then use any data anywhere

Comment: What are gonna do with `dataFromA, B, C, D`?

Comment: Why do you need `data` use`<B data={dataFromA} getReturn={setDataFromB} />` and call like `getReturn(someData);` in your component, won't this work?

Comment: @AshishKamble) dataFromA, B, C are only temporary data. The main purpose of TestComponent is to convert originalData to dataFromD. Do I need to set the temporary data (dataFromA, B, C,) to redux in this case? And I think there is no flexibility to delete one of the A, B, C, or D components.

Comment: @AshishKamble, @RaduDiță, @kiranvj) originalData may be an array of data. And A is `select` component, allow user to use drop-down list to select the data he wants. B is the keyword `input` to allow user to enter the keyword he wants in data. The function of C and D are similar to A and B.